# error while loading shared libraries: libext2fs.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: debian, debian-stretch

I tried to downgrade from debian 10 to debian 9, and after many `apt upgrade` or `aptitute safe-upgrade` and `full-upgrade`, when I rebooted the system it does not load and I get this error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libext2fs.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
The root filesystem on /dev/sda2 requires a manual fsck
```

I tried to get the file from another installation and put in the directory (with a live CD):

```
lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

But still the file seems to not be in the directory (I see it when I navigate directory with live CD).
What I get is this:

```
(initramfs)
```

With just few commands.

Comment: there's no question here.  start by running:  
fsck dev/sda2

Comment: i can't, i installed debian again.

Answer (score 1):

Just hit this myself after recovering from improperly pinned backports.

Reinstall e2fslibs and e2fsprogs and then update the initrd.

```
apt-get --reinstall install e2fsprogs e2fslibs
update-initramfs -u
```

(from memory)  You can pass -v while rebuilding the ramdisk and grep for ext to make sure the shared library is being included.

I used rescue mode from an install USB drive and let it make a chrooted mount & root shell for me.  I invoked bash to make the job easier.

Buster has stub packages for those two but Stretch needs them.